# Product variations on cart pages

Tags: wordpress

I have created variations (height and width) for my products using advanced custom field plugin. All variations are doing fine.

The problem is, after selecting variations when I click on the add to cart button, product is added to my cart.And When I click on the cart icon on the menu bar, it shows me the correct price of that product. But in cart page the price is displayed as 0.

If I select simple product, It is working fine.
How can I solve this problem???

Comment: Please include more details regarding the specific plugins/cart you're using, code, and screenshots if possible.

Comment: you should need to add the price on variations with variable types product .